# Case notification issue

Tags: email, case, account, territory

I have one requirement where I have to send email notification to account territory team of specific region (example West-WE) whenever case is opened for particular account of that region. Here only related users of the territory team of the account should get the email. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by standard process , you should go for batch class, if you want to do it based on any action then you should go for trigger otherwise you can go for batch class.

1. Query on Territory object to find the specific d for " West-WE" .
2. then query on UserTerritory object to find out the list of user for that particular territory.
3. send email to all users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are these steps you mentioned for trigger?